# Grails and Spring Security and plugins - unable to resolve class

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I added org.grails.plugins: spring-security-facebook: 0.15.3-Core2

During compilation I have error:

```
    [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
   [groovyc]C:\probionet2\target\work\plugins\spring-security-facebook-0.15.3-CORE2\src\groovy\com\the6hours\grails\springsecurity\facebook\DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class org.apache.log4j.Logger
   [groovyc] @ line 12, column 1.
   [groovyc] import org.apache.log4j.Logger
   [groovyc] ^
```

and etc...

Can help me?

I greet.

Adam

Comment: please take a new version, or add log4j to dependencies. logger left from older version of grails, current version doesn't have this line

Comment: Sorry, I use Grails in version 2.4.2

Comment: i current version of the plugin, it's 0.16

Comment: I trying install plugin 0.16 and I had three error type: @ line 220, column 13.
               encode(key) + '=' + encode(value?.toString() ?: '')

Comment: please open an issue, with complete stacktrace - https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-facebook/issues

Comment: or you could continue to use 0.15.x, just add log4j to dependencies